# Django sum on an external attribut

Tags: python, django, orm

I have an issue with database and sum in Django.
I have 3 tables: customer, order and orderLine.

For a report, I would like to calculate the sum of all line price for every order of a customer.

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    firstName = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    lastName = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    mail = models.EmailField(max_length=100)
    etc...

    def get_count_of_orders(self):
        return self.orders.count()

    def get_sum_line_prince_of_all_orders(self):
        ???????????
        return (sum_of_all_line_prince_all_orders)


class Order(models.Model):
    orderNum = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, related_name="orders")
    globalAmount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=4)
    ...

class OrderLine(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, related_name="ordersLines")
    linePrice = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=4)
    ...
```

I don't know what to set in get_sum_of_orders to get the right result.
I've trayed different things like annotate or aggregate.
But without success at the moment.

I didn't understand this process at the moment.

Could you help me?

Comment: How is an `OrderLine` related to a `Customer`? There seems to be no `ForeignKey`/... from `Order` to `OrderLine`, only to `Item`.

Comment: order and orderLine are related.Older line have a the primary key of order to do the link.

Comment: yes, but in your current models, there is no relation between the two (`ForeignKey`, `OneToOneField`, `ManyToManyField`, etc.)

Comment: I didn't copy all the class.But the 3 classes are linked.

Answer (score 0):

You can access all orders with:

```
self.orders.all()
```

and you can iterate them with:

```
sum = 0
for each_order in self.orders.all():
    sum += each_order.globalAmount
return sum
```

Here I presume that globalAmount is the amount you need to calculate.

If you need to reach OrderLine -> linePrice through each customer and calculate the sum of the linePrice(s) of each customer, try the following:

```
for each_order in self.orders.all():  #each order
    for each_OrderLine in each_order.ordersLines.all()
        sum += each_OrderLine.linePrice
```

Or you could use list comprehension:

```
sum([myorder.linePrice for myorder in order.ordersLines.all() for order in self.orders.all()])
```

Comment: hello,

Thanks for the answer.
Having 2 loops will required a lot of CPU no?
Is there a way to get the result form SQL directly?

Comment: Yes, there should be a way to do that but I am not familiar with SQL.

Also, use list comprehension instead of for loops as it is faster:

https://towardsdatascience.com/python-basics-list-comprehensions-631278f22c40#:~:text=The%20list%20comprehensions%20are%20more,example%20using%20a%20for%20loop.